# Eclipse plugin problem

Tags: eclipse-plugin

When ever I try to do soft ware updates through my Eclipse Galileo, I get the following error

Unable to connect to repository http://pydev.org/updates/content.xml

Connection timed out: connect

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using (just) http://pydev.org/updates as the url?  The "location" field should only have "http://pydev.org/updates", no content.xml.  Seems to be working fine for me (with Helios).

Actually I checked what happens when you use "http://pydev.org/updates/content.xml", and it does seem to give the type of error you describe. (You would think it could give a slightly better error, but oh well.)

Comment: Hi,I am using only http://pydev.org/updates....after it gives the error it shows content.xml..

Comment: No kidding?  And you're not behind a firewall or anything like that I assume?  That should be working fine, and I just confirmed the site is up a few minutes ago.

Comment: I looked into everythg...But i think I coudnt get through the problem. I installed it manually finally :)

Comment: Pretty weird, I'd be wondering if it's just the one site, or are other update sites broken too?

Answer (score 4):

That's a redirect to: http://update-production-pydev.s3.amazonaws.com/pydev/updates (so, you can try that directly).

If it still fails, it means that amazon is having issues (which means you'll have to try later again).

Cheers,